how to solve Type Error in CodeIgniter 4 Login Method?
I'm currently working on the login feature for my project and encountering an issue similar to one I had with user registration. I managed to solve the registration issue, but I'm still having trouble with the login method.
Here’s my do_login method:
`<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use \App\Models\UserModel; 

class Login extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo view('common/header');
        echo view('login');
        echo view('common/footer');
    }

    public function do_login()
    {
        $userModel = new UserModel();
        $email = $this->request->getPost('email');
        $password = $this->request->getPost('password');

        // Fetch user based on email
        $result = $userModel->where('email', $email)->first();

        // Check if a user was found and that the password field is a string
        if ($result->id > 0) {
            // Verify password
            if (password_verify($password, $result->password)) {
                $this->session->set("user", $result);
                // Handle successful login, e.g., redirect to a dashboard
            } else {
                echo 'Invalid email or password.';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Invalid email or password.';
        }
    }
}`

The error I’m getting is "Expected type 'string'. Found 'array|null'.intelephense(P1006)".(the $password is underlined)
For context, I faced a similar issue with the registration method and managed to resolve it. Here’s the registration method that works:
`
 `public function do_register(){
        $userModel = new UserModel();
        $name = $this->request->getPost('name');
        $email = $this->request->getPost('email');
        $password = $this->request->getPost('password');
        $mobile = $this->request->getPost('mobile');
        // Validate input
        if (is_string($password) && !empty($password)) {
            $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        } else {
            // Handle error: password is not valid
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Invalid password.');
        }
        $data= [
            'name'=>$name,
            'email'=>$email,
            'password'=> $hashedPassword,
            'Mobile_Number' => $mobile
        ];
        $r = $userModel->insert($data);
        if( $r )
        {
            echo "User Registered Sucessfully";
        }
        else{
            echo "Error during registration";
        }
    }``














